# How can I transfer all records in 1 DataGridView to another DataGridView?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have 1 `DataGridView` and I want to transfer all records to another `DataGridView`. How can I possibly do that?

```
dgvCourseList - 1st datagridview
dgvCourseHandled - 2nd datagridview
```

This is my code in transferring 1 record to another `DataGridView`:

```
Private Sub btnInsert_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnInsert.Click
    If (chckCourse(dgvCourselist.SelectedCells.Item(0).Value)) = True And (chckDup(dgvCourselist.SelectedCells.Item(0).Value)) = False Then
        dgvCoursesHandled.Rows.Add(dgvCourselist.SelectedCells.Item(0).Value)
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your almost on the right track.

```
if [check if row is selected from the dgvCourselist]


  dgvCourseHandled.Rows.Add(dgvCourseList.Cells("columnname").Value, _
                             repeat until all column in dgvCourseHandled are satisfied)
```

1. Identify how many columns in dgvcoursehandled and the column name. Tip: if you did not specify column name, please do so, "magic no" will not help you debug things if you have a lot of columns.
   e.g   dgvCourseList.Cells("columnname").Value
2. Identify all columns in dgvcourselist that will be pass into dgvcoursehandled

When you identify all of this follow the pseudocode above.

Answer (score 2):

```
Private Sub btnInsertAll_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnInsertAll.Click

        If (chckCourse(dgvCourselist.SelectedCells.Item(0).Value)) = True And (chckDup(dgvCourselist.SelectedCells.Item(0).Value)) = False Then
            For i As Integer = 0 To Me.dgvCourselist.Rows.Count - 1
                dgvCoursesHandled.Rows.Add(dgvCourselist.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value)
            Next

        End If
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Can also try this.

Copy the columns first:

```
For Each col As DataGridViewColumn In DataGridView1.Columns
        DataGridView2.Columns.Add(DirectCast(col.Clone, DataGridViewColumn))
Next
```

Then the data

```
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
    DataGridViewRow2.Rows.Add(row.Cells.Cast(Of DataGridViewCell).Select(Function(c) c.Value).ToArray)
Next
```

Source: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?678009-Copying-rows-and-columns-from-one-datagridview-to-another